# How to omit a storage policy rule based on a condition in bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have this bicep code to apply two rules to a storage account policy on an Azure Storage Account:

```
@description('Name of the storage account')
param name string

@description('Number of days before moving from Hot to Cool storage')
param hotToCoolDays int

@description('Number of days to housekeep blob storage')
param houseKeepDays int

// the storage account to apply the policy to
resource stg 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-08-01' existing = {
  name: name
}

resource sapolicy 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/managementPolicies@2021-02-01' = {
  name: '${name}/default'
  dependsOn: [
    stg
  ]
  properties: {
    policy: {
      rules: [ 
        {
          enabled: true
          name: 'hotToCoolAfter${hotToCoolDays}Days'
          type: 'Lifecycle'
          definition: {
            actions: {
              baseBlob: {
                tierToCool: {
                  daysAfterModificationGreaterThan: hotToCoolDays
                }
              }
            }
            filters: {
              blobTypes: [
                'blockBlob'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
        {
          enabled: true
          name: 'housekeepAfter${houseKeepDays}Days'
          type: 'Lifecycle'
          definition: {
            actions: {
              baseBlob: {
                delete: {
                  daysAfterModificationGreaterThan: houseKeepDays
                }
              }
            }
            filters: {
              blobTypes: [
                'blockBlob'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to omit the rule if either variable `hotToCoolDays` or `houseKeepDays` is 0. I've tried using `if` statement and the ternary operator but can't get either to work. Any ideas?

Comment: `if (!(hotToCoolDays == 0 || houseKeepDays == 0))` should work. Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Question is where does that code go? If `hotToCoolDays ==0` then I don't want to add the rule. If `houseKeepDays ==0` I don't want to run that rule. As I said I already tried an if statement on the line preceding `enabled: true`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with

```
@description('Number of days before moving from Cool to Cold storage')
param coolToColdDays int = 0

@description('Name of the storage account')
param name string

@description('Number of days before moving from Hot to Cool storage')
param hotToCoolDays int = 0

@description('Number of days to housekeep blob storage')
param houseKeepDays int = 0

var hotToCoolRule = [{
    name: 'hotToCoolRule'
    enabled: true
    type: 'Lifecycle'
    definition: {
      actions: {
        baseBlob: {
          tierToCool: {
            daysAfterModificationGreaterThan: hotToCoolDays
          }
        }
      }
      filters: {
        blobTypes: [
          'blockBlob'
        ]
      }
    }
  }]

  var coolToColdRule = [{
    name: 'coolToColdRule'
    enabled: true
    type: 'Lifecycle'
    definition: {
      actions: {
        baseBlob: {
          tierToCold: {
            daysAfterModificationGreaterThan: coolToColdDays
          }
        }
      }
      filters: {
        blobTypes: [
          'blockBlob'
        ]
      }
    }
  }]

var houseKeepRule = [{
    name: 'housekeepRule'
    enabled: true
    type: 'Lifecycle'
    definition: {
      actions: {
        baseBlob: {
          delete: {
            daysAfterModificationGreaterThan: houseKeepDays
          }
        }
      }
      filters: {
        blobTypes: [
          'blockBlob'
        ]
      }
    }
  }]

var rules = concat(
  (hotToCoolDays > 0) ? hotToCoolRule : [],
  // (coolToColdDays > 0) ? coolToColdRule : [], this line is commented out as it's not available yet (PREVIEW)
  (houseKeepDays > 0) ? houseKeepRule : []
)

resource stg 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-08-01' existing = {
  name: name
}

resource sapolicy 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/managementPolicies@2022-09-01' = if (! empty(rules)) {
  name: 'default'
  parent: stg
  properties: {
    policy: {
      rules: rules
    }
  }
}
```